# Kafka connector's task status are different when queried against different kafka connect nodes in a clustered enviroment

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

We have a 3 node Kafka connect cluster running version 5.5.4 in distributed mode. We are observing a strange issue regarding connector's task status.

The REST calls to node 1 and 2 are returning different results.

The first node returned this result:

```
{
   "connector":{
      "state":"RUNNING",
      "worker_id":"x.com:8083"
   },
   "name":"connector",
   "type":"source",
   "tasks":[
      
   ]
}
```

Yes the task is empty where as the other node returned this result:

```
{
   "connector":{
      "state":"RUNNING",
      "worker_id":"x.com:8083"
   },
   "name":"connector...",
   "type":"source",
   "tasks":[
      {
         "id":0,
         "state":"RUNNING",
         "worker_id":"x.com:8083"
      }
   ]
}
```

As mentioned in this doc https://docs.confluent.io/home/connect/userguide.html#kconnect-internal-topics, I have configured group.id, config.storage.topic, offset.storage.topic and  status.storage.topic with identical values in all 3 nodes.

I did go through connect-statuses-0 data directory and the file sizes for log, index and timestamp are all identical in node 1 and node 2. I don't know what is the .snapshot file but I see only one with root user/group in first node where as I see 2 of them in the 2nd node. One owned by root user/group and the other owned by our custom created user. Not sure this has anything to do with this problem.

Please guide me in identifying the root cause for this problem. If I do need to check any configuration, please let me know.

Comment: I've seen this happen when the listeners settings are misconfigured (the nodes cannot talk to each other, and will therefore only know about local tasks). Can you share your connect worker properties file?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. sorry. we have reverted the setup.